# JEditorPane полностью не отрисовывает картинки

Tags: изображения, java

Приветствую, почтенные!

`JEditorPane` используется для вывода html с картинками.
 В java 8,7 часто, в 6 реже не дорисовывает картинки даже в полноэкранном режиме. `revalidate()`, `repaint()` не помогают.

Проявляется на примере работы простейшего браузера типа http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/javax.swing/how-to-create-a-simple-browser-in-swing-18.html .
[Скриншот глюка](http://hostingkartinok.com/show-image.php?id=d36c994140ce89c3ddf4846f36e5d8d5)

[Нашел средство](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1353113?start=0&tstart=0). Эта часть помогла

> I came across this thread when I was
> searching for solutions to problems
> with the asynchronous loading of HTML
> pages by the JEditorPane.setPage
> method (JTextPane is essentially the
> same so far these problems are
> concerned). According to the API, you
> should be able to use a
> property-change listener to be
> informed of when loading of an HTML
> page is complete. However, when we
> tried this, it was clear that the
> listener was being called before all
> the images in the page had been
> loaded.
>
> It is possible to workaround this bug
> by forcing synchronous loading of the
> images. The following solutions are
> probably too late for PaulCharo, but
> may be of use to other people.
>
> To force synchronous loading of images
> you need to override methods in the
> HTMLEditor.HTMLFactory and
> HTMLEditorKit classes:

```
static class MyViewFactory
extends HTMLEditorKit.HTMLFactory
{
    @Override
    public View create (Element elem)
    {
        View view = super.create (elem);
        if (view instanceof ImageView)
                ((ImageView) view).setLoadsSynchronously (true);
        return view;
    }
}

static class MyHTMLEditorKit
extends HTMLEditorKit
{
    @Override
    public ViewFactory getViewFactory ()
    {
        return new MyViewFactory ();
    }
}

editorPane.setEditorKit (new MyHTMLEditorKit ());
```

> This should ensure that all images
> have been loaded by the time that the
> "page" property-change listener is
> called (see [JEditorPane.setPage
> API|http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JEditorPane.html#setPage(java.net.URL)]),
> but there still seems to be something
> queued on the event dispatch queue
> that you need to wait for. This means
> that you have to use a property-change
> listener that looks something like:
>     This should ensure that all images have been loaded by the time that the
> "page" property-change listener is
> called (see [JEditorPane.setPage
> API|http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JEditorPane.html#setPage(java.net.URL)]),
> but there still seems to be something
> queued on the event dispatch queue
> that you need to wait for. This means
> that you have to use a property-change
> listener that looks something like:

```
editorPane.addPropertyChangeListener (
    new PropertyChangeListener ()
    {
        public void propertyChange (PropertyChangeEvent e)
        {
            if (e.getPropertyName ().equals ("page"))
            {
                EventQueue.invokeLater (
                   new Runnable ()
                   {`

                       public void run ()
                       {
                            // The page, including images, should now be loaded!
                           .....
                       }
                    });
            }
        }
});
```

Comment: А приложите скриншот, как это выглядит.

Comment: Бывает, когда страница из интернета грузится, какие-то картинки недогружаются и кусками выводятся. То же самое, только все уже есть на локальном компьютере и картинки маленькие. Завтра постараюсь приложить скриншот.